# How I can fetch the API correctly

Tags: javascript

I have created 10 , each  display one id in API. I have used querySelectorAll to find all the  and use for loop to make the content of each contains one id in API but when I try to code, as you can see, one  will contain all ten id and I don't know how to make it possible

```js
function onResponse(response) {
    return response.json();
}

function data(data) {
    //create a function to display the element 
    var htmls = data.map(function(post) {
        return `<li>
                <h2> ${post.id}</h2>
                </li>`
    });

    
    var html = htmls.join('');
    const p = document.querySelectorAll('span');
    for (let i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        p[i].innerHTML = html;
    }

}
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(onResponse).then(data);
```

```html
   

<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>

            <span></span>

            <span></span>

            <span></span>
            <span></span>

            <span></span>



           
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`html` is already the HTML of each `id`. You are assigning it to each `span`'s `innerHTML`, causing there to be 9 duplicates.

Instead, just assign to the `span`'s parent's `innerHTML`:

```js
function onResponse(response) {
    return response.json();
}

function data(data) {
    //create a function to display the element 
    var htmls = data.map(function(post) {
        return `<li>
                <h2> ${post.id}</h2>
                </li>`
    });

    
    var html = htmls.join('');
    const div = document.querySelector('div');
    div.innerHTML = html;

}
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users').then(onResponse).then(data);
```

```html
<body>
    <form>
        <div>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>

            <span></span>

            <span></span>

            <span></span>
            <span></span>

            <span></span>



           
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```